# How do I set Unity launcher to auto hide

Tags: unity, launcher

I just installed 13.10, and I can't seem to find how set the Unity Panel (launcher) to  auto-hide. Can someone direct me to where the option is? A search in the settings shows no results.

A search on askubuntu reveals several threads with hiding issues and how to fix them using tools. But doesn't tell me where I can find the simple auto-hide option to begin with. Does the default installation contain such an option, and if so, where? Do I need to install some tools to get this option? If so, shouldn't such a basic option already be there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open *System Settings*.
2. Click on *Appearance*.
3. In the "Behaviour" tab, enable "Auto-hide the Launcher"

Comment: Thanks a lot. Why doesn't it show up when I search it in the settings. I searched for "auto-hide", "auto", "hide" etc...

Comment: @Ubuntu_kwr I suspect it is because the settings search is not very deep, i.e. it only searches the name and description of the buttons from the settings main page

Answer (score 0):

- System Settings
- Appearance -> Behavior -> Autohide the luncher

[image: System settings -> Appearance]